# Crop ternary plot

Tags: pgfplots, path-clipping, ternary-diagram

I want to crop the top part of the ternary plot given below at x = 0.7 because I don't have any datapoints in that region and want to save space. How can I do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}[
ternary limits relative=false,
xlabel= x, 
ylabel= y, 
zlabel= z,
width=9.5cm,
height=9.5cm,
xmin=0.3,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.7,
zmin=0,
zmax=0.7,
clip=false,
disabledatascaling,
]
\addplot3[only marks, mark options={black}]
table {
0.63    0.37    0
0.43    0.57    0
0.56    0   0.44
0.57    0.1 0.33
0.40    0.35    0.25
0.45    0.31    0.24
};
\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So you want to truncate the triangle, resulting in a pentagon?

Comment: @Jake I would just like to chop off the top part so that it becomes a trapezoid.

Comment: Oops, of course, that's what I meant. I'm not entirely sure that that's a very good idea: It'll make it much harder for the reader to understand what kind of diagram they have in front of them. Not having the axes run from 0 to 1 already makes reading the diagram harder, because now the reader has to consciously refer to the tick labels to see what kind of mixture they're looking at, while the advantage of the standard ternary diagram is that it makes it quite easy to get a "feel" for the data. Could you point to a reference where you've seen a cropped ternary diagram?

Comment: On the second last page of this journal article you can find such a diagram: http://dx.doi.org/10.2355/isijinternational.40.554 I agree that it becomes more confusing but it's a more efficient use of space.

Comment: Here is a more easily accessible example: http://glassproperties.com/phase-separation/

Comment: Fair enough. I can't think of an elegant way to achieve this. Looks like this would be a good feature request. If you just need to get this working for a limited number of plots, you might be able to get away with manually covering the unwanted parts with a white area and adjusting the bounding box.

Comment: It would indeed be a nice feature. I can as you suggest also acieve this manually with some effort.

Comment: Would you mind posting your manual way of doing this as an answer? It might help other people with the same problem to work around the issue until this is properly implemented.

Comment: I should have said that I believe I can achieve this manually but I don't have time to work with it right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Jakes suggestion

---

First you need to find out what region to paint over in white. This is best done in the axis coordinate system, which you can use via `(axis cs:<coordinate>)`. This is a little strange, as the x-axis is the one pointing in 120° direction while the y-axis points in 240° direction. However it is quite possible to define e.g. the following path:

```
\fill[red,opacity=0.3] (axis cs: 0.7,0.3) -- (axis cs:0.7,0.0) -- (axis cs:0.65,-0.05) -- (axis cs:0.65,-0.1) -- (axis cs:1.1,-0.1) -- (axis cs:1.1,0) -- (axis cs:0.8,0.3) -- cycle;
```

Which will lead to the following output:

[image]

Next, you'll need to reset the current boundin box and create a new one. This has to be done *outside* of the axis environment, so unfortunately you won't be able to use the axis coordinate system any more. Fortunately,  for the last axis environment a node named `current axis` is defined. The normal anchors like `south east` only contain the plot but not the labels. However there are  special anchors like `outer south west` which you can use. As not the whole plot area is needed, you can use the *calc* library for computations with coordinates. So the lines

```
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path (current axis.outer south west) rectangle ($(current axis.outer north east)+(0,-3.5)$);
```

put after the axis environment will yield

[image]

which look quite good yet. However, the upper edge is gray and only half width as you just painted over it, so you'll have to draw it again via `\draw (axis cs: 0.7,0.3) -- (axis cs:0.7,0.0);`. Furthermore the upper edge does not have any ticks, and I don't know how to let *pgfplots* draw some there.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}[
ternary limits relative=false,
xlabel= x, 
ylabel= y, 
zlabel= z,
width=9.5cm,
height=9.5cm,
xmin=0.3,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.7,
zmin=0,
zmax=0.7,
clip=false,
disabledatascaling,
]
\addplot3[only marks, mark options={black}]
table {
0.63    0.37    0
0.43    0.57    0
0.56    0   0.44
0.57    0.1 0.33
0.40    0.35    0.25
0.45    0.31    0.24
};
\fill[white,opacity=1] (axis cs: 0.7,0.3) -- (axis cs:0.7,0.0) -- (axis cs:0.65,-0.05) -- (axis cs:0.65,-0.1) -- (axis cs:1.1,-0.1) -- (axis cs:1.1,0) -- (axis cs:0.8,0.3) -- cycle;
\draw (axis cs: 0.7,0.3) -- (axis cs:0.7,0.0);
\end{ternaryaxis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path (current axis.outer south west) rectangle ($(current axis.outer north east)+(0,-3.5)$);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

### Full manual approach

---

Doing the whole plot has the advantage that you can influence everything just the way you like it, but the disadvantage that it only has the features you provided, and it may take a while to make this reusable. Here's an idea that *might be*  a starting point:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[   x={(0:1cm)},
    y={(60:1cm)}
]
```

Set up the x-axis in 0° direction and the y axis in 60° direction.

```
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,3) -- (7,3) -- (3,7) -- (0,7) -- cycle;
        \foreach \z in {0,...,6}
        {   \foreach \x in {3,...,7}
            {   \draw[help lines] (\z,\x) -- ++ (1,0)
                    (\z,\x) -- ++ (0,1)
                    (\z+1,\x) -- ++ (-1,1);
            }
        }
    \end{scope}
```

Clip the drawing area and draw the triangular grid.

```
    \draw (0,3) -- (7,3) -- (3,7) -- (0,7) -- cycle;
```

Draw the outline of the plot.

```
    \foreach \x/\z in {0.63/0, 0.43/0, 0.56/0.44, 0.57/0.33, 0.40/0.25, 0.45/0.24}
    {   \fill (\z*10,\x*10) circle (0.07cm);
    }
```

Draw the data points. Only the x- and z-components were used, as y is not independant of them.

```
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=1}
```

Set up parameters to print math numbers with one digit precision

```
    \foreach \z in {0,...,7}
    {   \draw (\z,3) -- ++(0,-0.2) node[below] {\pgfmathparse{\z/10}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
    }
    \foreach \x in {3,...,7}
    {   \draw (0,\x) -- ++(-0.14,0.14) node[above left] {\pgfmathparse{(10-\x)/10}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
        \draw (10-\x,\x) -- ++(0.2,0) node[right] {\pgfmathparse{(\x)/10}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
    }
    \foreach \z in {1,...,3}
    {   \draw (\z,7) -- ++(-0.14,0.14) node[above left] {\pgfmathparse{(3-\z)/10}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
    }
```

Draw the tick lines and label them, also for the upper edge of the plot.

```
    \node[below,font=\bfseries,draw, circle, minimum size=0.7cm] at (4,2) {z};
    \node[right,font=\bfseries,draw, circle, minimum size=0.7cm] at (5,6) {x};
    \node[above left,font=\bfseries,draw, circle, minimum size=0.7cm] at (-1,7) {y};
```

Draw nodes for the axis labels.

```
    \foreach \x/\z [count=\c] in {7/3, 7/0, 3/0, 3/7}
    {   \draw[<-,red] (\z,\x) -- ++(-45+\c*90:2) node[circle,fill=white] {(\z,\x)};
    }
```

Just some helper nodes to show a few coordinates.

```
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   x={(0:1cm)},
    y={(60:1cm)}
]
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,3) -- (7,3) -- (3,7) -- (0,7) -- cycle;
        \foreach \z in {0,...,6}
        {   \foreach \x in {3,...,7}
            {   \draw[help lines] (\z,\x) -- ++ (1,0)
                    (\z,\x) -- ++ (0,1)
                    (\z+1,\x) -- ++ (-1,1);
            }
        }
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,3) -- (7,3) -- (3,7) -- (0,7) -- cycle;
    \foreach \x/\z in {0.63/0, 0.43/0, 0.56/0.44, 0.57/0.33, 0.40/0.25, 0.45/0.24}
    {   \fill (\z*10,\x*10) circle (0.07cm);
    }
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=1}
    \foreach \z in {0,...,7}
    {   \draw (\z,3) -- ++(0,-0.2) node[below] {\pgfmathparse{\z/10}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
    }
    \foreach \x in {3,...,7}
    {   \draw (0,\x) -- ++(-0.14,0.14) node[above left] {\pgfmathparse{(10-\x)/10}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
        \draw (10-\x,\x) -- ++(0.2,0) node[right] {\pgfmathparse{(\x)/10}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
    }
    \foreach \z in {1,...,3}
    {   \draw (\z,7) -- ++(-0.14,0.14) node[above left] {\pgfmathparse{(3-\z)/10}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
    }
    \node[below,font=\bfseries,draw, circle, minimum size=0.7cm] at (4,2) {z};
    \node[right,font=\bfseries,draw, circle, minimum size=0.7cm] at (5,6) {x};
    \node[above left,font=\bfseries,draw, circle, minimum size=0.7cm] at (-1,7) {y};
    \foreach \x/\z [count=\c] in {7/3, 7/0, 3/0, 3/7}
    {   \draw[<-,red] (\z,\x) -- ++(-45+\c*90:2) node[circle,fill=white] {(\z,\x)};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]